# Tensorflow Probability - MCMC sample chain - TypeError: Tensor is unhashable - Mac M1

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tensorflow, conda

I am trying to run the example in the tensorflow documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/mcmc/effective_sample_size). However, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Tensor is unhashable. Instead, use tensor.ref() as the key.
```

I have added below

- Traceback
- Output of `conda list`
- Output of `conda info`

## Traceback

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/hy/57_f4xcx08b0ls2_nwwfjscr0000gn/T/ipykernel_19414/3526934965.py in <module>
      6 
      7 # Get 1000 states from one chain.
----> 8 states = tfp.mcmc.sample_chain(
      9     num_burnin_steps=200,
     10     num_results=1000,

~/miniforge3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/mcmc/sample.py in sample_chain(num_results, current_state, previous_kernel_results, kernel, num_burnin_steps, num_steps_between_results, trace_fn, return_final_kernel_results, parallel_iterations, name)
    324         current_state)
    325     if previous_kernel_results is None:
--> 326       previous_kernel_results = kernel.bootstrap_results(current_state)
    327 
    328     if trace_fn is None:

~/miniforge3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/mcmc/hmc.py in bootstrap_results(self, init_state)
    558   def bootstrap_results(self, init_state):
    559     """Creates initial `previous_kernel_results` using a supplied `state`."""
--> 560     kernel_results = self._impl.bootstrap_results(init_state)
    561     if self.step_size_update_fn is not None:
    562       step_size_assign = self.step_size_update_fn(self.step_size, None)  # pylint: disable=not-callable

~/miniforge3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/mcmc/metropolis_hastings.py in bootstrap_results(self, init_state)
    263         name=mcmc_util.make_name(self.name, 'mh', 'bootstrap_results'),
    264         values=[init_state]):
--> 265       pkr = self.inner_kernel.bootstrap_results(init_state)
    266       if not has_target_log_prob(pkr):
    267         raise ValueError(

~/miniforge3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/mcmc/hmc.py in bootstrap_results(self, init_state)
    770           init_target_log_prob,
    771           init_grads_target_log_prob,
--> 772       ] = mcmc_util.maybe_call_fn_and_grads(self.target_log_prob_fn, init_state)
    773       if self._store_parameters_in_results:
    774         return UncalibratedHamiltonianMonteCarloKernelResults(

~/miniforge3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/mcmc/internal/util.py in maybe_call_fn_and_grads(fn, fn_arg_list, result, grads, check_non_none_grads, name)
    231     fn_arg_list = (list(fn_arg_list) if is_list_like(fn_arg_list)
    232                    else [fn_arg_list])
--> 233     result, grads = _value_and_gradients(fn, fn_arg_list, result, grads)
    234     if not all(r.dtype.is_floating
    235                for r in (result if is_list_like(result) else [result])):  # pylint: disable=superfluous-parens

~/miniforge3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/mcmc/internal/util.py in _value_and_gradients(fn, fn_arg_list, result, grads, name)
    190 
    191     if result is None:
--> 192       result = fn(*fn_arg_list)
    193       if grads is None and tf.executing_eagerly():
    194         # Ensure we disable bijector cacheing in eager mode.

~/miniforge3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/distributions/distribution.py in log_prob(self, value, name, **kwargs)
    864         values of type `self.dtype`.
    865     """
--> 866     return self._call_log_prob(value, name, **kwargs)
    867 
    868   def _call_prob(self, value, name, **kwargs):

~/miniforge3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/distributions/distribution.py in _call_log_prob(self, value, name, **kwargs)
    846           value, name="value", dtype_hint=self.dtype)
    847       if hasattr(self, "_log_prob"):
--> 848         return self._log_prob(value, **kwargs)
    849       if hasattr(self, "_prob"):
    850         return tf.math.log(self._prob(value, **kwargs))

~/miniforge3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/internal/distribution_util.py in _fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2092     @functools.wraps(fn)
   2093     def _fn(*args, **kwargs):
-> 2094       return fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2095 
   2096     if _fn.__doc__ is None:

~/miniforge3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/distributions/mvn_linear_operator.py in _log_prob(self, x)
    208   @distribution_util.AppendDocstring(_mvn_sample_note)
    209   def _log_prob(self, x):
--> 210     return super(MultivariateNormalLinearOperator, self)._log_prob(x)
    211 
    212   @distribution_util.AppendDocstring(_mvn_sample_note)

~/miniforge3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/distributions/transformed_distribution.py in _log_prob(self, y, **kwargs)
    399     # For caching to work, it is imperative that the bijector is the first to
    400     # modify the input.
--> 401     x = self.bijector.inverse(y, **bijector_kwargs)
    402     event_ndims = self._maybe_get_static_event_ndims()
    403 

~/miniforge3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/bijectors/bijector.py in inverse(self, y, name, **kwargs)
    975       NotImplementedError: if `_inverse` is not implemented.
    976     """
--> 977     return self._call_inverse(y, name, **kwargs)
    978 
    979   def _compute_inverse_log_det_jacobian_with_caching(

~/miniforge3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/bijectors/bijector.py in _call_inverse(self, y, name, **kwargs)
    944       if not self._is_injective:  # No caching for non-injective
    945         return self._inverse(y, **kwargs)
--> 946       mapping = self._lookup(y=y, kwargs=kwargs)
    947       if mapping.x is not None:
    948         return mapping.x

~/miniforge3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/bijectors/bijector.py in _lookup(self, x, y, kwargs)
   1344     if y is not None:
   1345       # We removed y at caching time. Add it back if we lookup successfully.
-> 1346       mapping = self._from_y[y].get(subkey, mapping).merge(y=y)
   1347     return mapping
   1348 

~/miniforge3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/bijectors/bijector.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    149   def __getitem__(self, key):
    150     weak_key = HashableWeakRef(key, lambda w: self.pop(w, None))
--> 151     return super(WeakKeyDefaultDict, self).__getitem__(weak_key)
    152 
    153   # This is the "DefaultDict" part.

~/miniforge3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/bijectors/bijector.py in __hash__(self)
    179     x = self()
    180     if not isinstance(x, np.ndarray):
--> 181       return hash(x)
    182     # Note: The following logic can never be reached by the public API because
    183     # the bijector base class always calls `convert_to_tensor` before accessing

~/miniforge3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in __hash__(self)
    828     if (Tensor._USE_EQUALITY and executing_eagerly_outside_functions() and
    829         (g is None or g.building_function)):
--> 830       raise TypeError("Tensor is unhashable. "
    831                       "Instead, use tensor.ref() as the key.")
    832     else:

TypeError: Tensor is unhashable. Instead, use tensor.ref() as the key.
```

## Conda List

```
# packages in environment at /Users/maurocamara/miniforge3/envs/tf_env:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
absl-py                   0.13.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
aiohttp                   3.7.4.post0      py38hea4295b_0    conda-forge
anyio                     3.2.1            py38h10201cd_0    conda-forge
appnope                   0.1.2            py38h10201cd_1    conda-forge
argon2-cffi               20.1.0           py38hea4295b_2    conda-forge
astor                     0.8.1              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
astunparse                1.6.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
async-timeout             3.0.1                   py_1000    conda-forge
async_generator           1.10                       py_0    conda-forge
attrs                     21.2.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
babel                     2.9.1              pyh44b312d_0    conda-forge
backcall                  0.2.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
backports                 1.0                        py_2    conda-forge
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
bleach                    3.3.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
blinker                   1.4                        py_1    conda-forge
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py38hea4295b_1001    conda-forge
c-ares                    1.17.1               h27ca646_1    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2021.5.30            h4653dfc_0    conda-forge
cached-property           1.5.2                hd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
cached_property           1.5.2              pyha770c72_1    conda-forge
cachetools                4.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2021.5.30        py38h10201cd_0    conda-forge
cffi                      1.14.6           py38h0957451_0    conda-forge
chardet                   4.0.0            py38h10201cd_1    conda-forge
charset-normalizer        2.0.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
click                     8.0.1            py38h10201cd_0    conda-forge
cloudpickle               1.6.0                      py_0    conda-forge
cryptography              3.4.7            py38h3c0dae5_0    conda-forge
cycler                    0.10.0                     py_2    conda-forge
dataclasses               0.8                pyhc8e2a94_1    conda-forge
debugpy                   1.3.0            py38h6f2b01f_0    conda-forge
decorator                 5.0.9              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
entrypoints               0.3             pyhd8ed1ab_1003    conda-forge
freetype                  2.10.4               h17b34a0_1    conda-forge
gast                      0.5.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
google-auth               1.33.1             pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.1                      py_2    conda-forge
google-pasta              0.2.0              pyh8c360ce_0    conda-forge
grpcio                    1.38.1           py38h69ee544_0    conda-forge
h5py                      3.3.0           nompi_py38hb525b2d_100    conda-forge
hdf5                      1.10.6          nompi_h0fc092c_1114    conda-forge
idna                      3.1                pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
importlib-metadata        4.6.1            py38h10201cd_0    conda-forge
ipykernel                 6.0.3            py38h2cb4d76_0    conda-forge
ipython                   7.25.0           py38h2cb4d76_1    conda-forge
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                      py_1    conda-forge
ipywidgets                7.6.3              pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
jbig                      2.1               h3422bc3_2003    conda-forge
jedi                      0.18.0           py38h10201cd_2    conda-forge
jinja2                    3.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jpeg                      9d                   h27ca646_0    conda-forge
json5                     0.9.5              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
jsonschema                3.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_3    conda-forge
jupyter                   1.0.0            py38h10201cd_6    conda-forge
jupyter_client            6.1.7                      py_0    anaconda
jupyter_console           6.4.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              4.7.1            py38h10201cd_0    conda-forge
jupyter_server            1.9.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab                3.0.16             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.2              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_server         2.6.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_widgets        1.0.0              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
keras-preprocessing       1.1.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
kiwisolver                1.3.1            py38h1670459_1    conda-forge
krb5                      1.19.1               hd92b7a7_0    conda-forge
lcms2                     2.12                 had6a04f_0    conda-forge
lerc                      2.2.1                h9f76cd9_0    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0                9_openblas    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.9.0                9_openblas    conda-forge
libcurl                   7.77.0               h8fe1914_0    conda-forge
libcxx                    12.0.1               h168391b_0    conda-forge
libdeflate                1.7                  h27ca646_5    conda-forge
libedit                   3.1.20191231         hc8eb9b7_2    conda-forge
libev                     4.33                 h642e427_1    conda-forge
libffi                    3.3                  h9f76cd9_2    conda-forge
libgfortran               5.0.0.dev0      11_0_1_hf114ba7_22    conda-forge
libgfortran5              11.0.1.dev0         hf114ba7_22    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.9.0                9_openblas    conda-forge
libnghttp2                1.43.0               hf3018f0_0    conda-forge
libopenblas               0.3.15          openmp_hf330de4_1    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.37               hf7e6567_2    conda-forge
libprotobuf               3.17.2               hccf11d3_1    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.18               h27ca646_1    conda-forge
libssh2                   1.9.0                hb80f160_6    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.3.0                hc6122e1_1    conda-forge
libwebp-base              1.2.0                h27ca646_2    conda-forge
llvm-openmp               12.0.1               hf3c4609_0    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.9.3                h9f76cd9_0    conda-forge
markdown                  3.3.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
markupsafe                2.0.1            py38hea4295b_0    conda-forge
matplotlib                3.4.2            py38h150bfb4_0    conda-forge
matplotlib-base           3.4.2            py38hb140015_0    conda-forge
matplotlib-inline         0.1.2              pyhd8ed1ab_2    conda-forge
mistune                   0.8.4           py38hea4295b_1004    conda-forge
multidict                 5.1.0            py38hea4295b_1    conda-forge
nbclassic                 0.3.1              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
nbclient                  0.5.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nbconvert                 6.1.0            py38h10201cd_0    conda-forge
nbformat                  5.1.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.2                  h9aa5885_4    conda-forge
nest-asyncio              1.5.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
notebook                  6.4.0              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
numpy                     1.19.5           py38hbf7bb01_2    conda-forge
oauthlib                  3.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
olefile                   0.46               pyh9f0ad1d_1    conda-forge
openjpeg                  2.4.0                h062765e_1    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1k               h27ca646_0    conda-forge
opt_einsum                3.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
packaging                 21.0               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pandocfilters             1.4.2                      py_1    conda-forge
parso                     0.8.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pexpect                   4.8.0              pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5                   py_1003    conda-forge
pillow                    8.3.1            py38h02acf36_0    conda-forge
pip                       20.2.4                     py_0    conda-forge
plotly                    5.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
prometheus_client         0.11.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
prompt-toolkit            3.0.19             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
prompt_toolkit            3.0.19               hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
protobuf                  3.17.2           py38h6f2b01f_0    conda-forge
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
pyasn1                    0.4.8                      py_0    conda-forge
pyasn1-modules            0.2.7                      py_0    conda-forge
pycparser                 2.20               pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
pygments                  2.9.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyjwt                     2.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyopenssl                 20.0.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyparsing                 2.4.7              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
pyrsistent                0.17.3           py38hea4295b_2    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.7.1            py38h10201cd_3    conda-forge
python                    3.8.10          hf9733c0_1_cpython    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0    anaconda
python-flatbuffers        2.0                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python_abi                3.8                      2_cp38    conda-forge
pytz                      2021.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyu2f                     0.1.5              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyzmq                     22.1.0           py38h51b17a6_0    conda-forge
readline                  8.1                  hedafd6a_0    conda-forge
requests                  2.26.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
requests-oauthlib         1.3.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
requests-unixsocket       0.2.0                      py_0    conda-forge
rsa                       4.7.2              pyh44b312d_0    conda-forge
scipy                     1.7.0            py38hd0c9ec0_0    conda-forge
send2trash                1.7.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
setuptools                49.6.0           py38h10201cd_3    conda-forge
six                       1.16.0             pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
sniffio                   1.2.0            py38h10201cd_1    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.36.0               h72a2b83_0    conda-forge
tenacity                  8.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tensorboard               2.4.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.8.0              pyh44b312d_0    conda-forge
tensorflow                2.4.0rc0                 pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-addons         0.11.2                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-estimator      2.5.0              pyh81a9013_1    conda-forge
tensorflow-probability    0.7                        py_1    conda-forge
termcolor                 1.1.0                      py_2    conda-forge
terminado                 0.10.1           py38h10201cd_0    conda-forge
testpath                  0.5.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.10               hf7e6567_1    conda-forge
tornado                   6.1              py38hea4295b_1    conda-forge
traitlets                 5.0.5                      py_0    conda-forge
typeguard                 2.12.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing-extensions         3.10.0.0             hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing_extensions         3.10.0.0           pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
urllib3                   1.26.6             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
webencodings              0.5.1                      py_1    conda-forge
websocket-client          0.57.0           py38h10201cd_4    conda-forge
werkzeug                  2.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
wheel                     0.36.2             pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
widgetsnbextension        3.5.1            py38h10201cd_4    conda-forge
wrapt                     1.12.1           py38hea4295b_3    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.5                h642e427_1    conda-forge
yarl                      1.6.3            py38hea4295b_2    conda-forge
zeromq                    4.3.4                h9f76cd9_0    conda-forge
zipp                      3.5.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11            h31e879b_1009    conda-forge
zstd                      1.5.0                h861e0a7_0    conda-forge
```

## Conda Info

```
     active environment : tf_env
    active env location : /Users/maurocamara/miniforge3/envs/tf_env
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /Users/maurocamara/.condarc
 populated config files : /Users/maurocamara/miniforge3/.condarc
                          /Users/maurocamara/.condarc
          conda version : 4.10.3
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.9.6.final.0
       virtual packages : __osx=11.2.3=0
                          __unix=0=0
                          __archspec=1=arm64
       base environment : /Users/maurocamara/miniforge3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /Users/maurocamara/miniforge3/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
          package cache : /Users/maurocamara/miniforge3/pkgs
                          /Users/maurocamara/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /Users/maurocamara/miniforge3/envs
                          /Users/maurocamara/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-arm64
             user-agent : conda/4.10.3 requests/2.26.0 CPython/3.9.6 Darwin/20.3.0 OSX/11.2.3
                UID:GID : 501:20
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not show any error when I tried replicating the same code in the `conda` environment.

There could be a version incompatibility issue as per this [Tested build configurations](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#cpu_2) because traceback error shows `Python 3.8` but conda info shows you have `Python 3.9.6` installed in conda. Please try again by upgrading `TensorFlow` into the latest version.

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

Please check the replicated code here:

```
!pip install tensorflow_probability

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
tfd = tfp.distributions

target = tfd.MultivariateNormalDiag(scale_diag=[1., 2.])

# Get 1000 states from one chain.
states = tfp.mcmc.sample_chain(
    num_burnin_steps=200,
    num_results=1000,
    current_state=tf.constant([0., 0.]),
    trace_fn=None,
    kernel=tfp.mcmc.HamiltonianMonteCarlo(
      target_log_prob_fn=target.log_prob,
      step_size=0.05,
      num_leapfrog_steps=20))
print(states.shape)
#==> (1000, 2)

ess = tfp.mcmc.effective_sample_size(states, filter_beyond_positive_pairs=True)
print(ess.shape)
#==> Shape (2,) Tensor

mean, variance = tf.nn.moments(states, axes=0)
standard_error = tf.sqrt(variance / ess)
```

Output:

```
(1000, 2)
(2,)
```